# How to delete files of same extension in Windows

Tags: windows, file, command, registry, explorer

I am now facing a great problem. I don't know how many files has come to my computer with unknown extensions (such as: .pxv,.cf)

I don't need these files. Can you give any command by which all the files of  such extension in my computer will gone forever?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you should do something like this you should be careful and find out what files you will be deleting and if you are deleting system files. What exact problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I've not seen such files in my system till now। But they are in other directory. I think these are may be viruses. Besides, these are making my small hard disk full. So I want to get rid of these. I hate antivirus softwares. Because most of them void privacy. That's why I want to delete these by programing or registry.